# Server Error in '/' Application on IE Only

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

The error details:

"Could not load file or assembly 'RSSharePointSoapProxy, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. "

The Central Admin site works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I only get this error with IE and EDGE.

Why does it work in Chrome and not IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all browsers support all report functionality in Reporting Services.

For more information on browser support, see [Browser Support for Reporting Services and Power View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/browser-support-for-reporting-services-and-power-view?view=sql-server-2017).

The possible reason for the issue does not happen when using Chrome is the Reporting Services does not work in this browser. Check your version of Chrome and the version of Reporting Services.

The “Could not load file or assembly” issue happens because of missing or corrupted RSSharePointSoapProxy dll due to un-installation of Reporting Services Add-In.

To resolve it, you need to install Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint technologies.

Check the following blog for more information:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24964.could-not-load-file-or-assembly-rssharepointsoapproxy.aspx